# Use of @RequiredArgsConstructor on conditional constructor

Tags: java, constructor, lombok

I am using Lombok to move all the hardcoded public/private constructors in my entire project.
Here is a special use-case where there are two member variables. But one parameter is passed as paramter in constructor to set the property. How can I use @RequiredArgsConstructor in this scenario:

How can I use @RequiredArgsConstructor to convert this constructor?

```
public ObjectToString(final String delimiter) {
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
        this.functions = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Class template:

```
public final class ObjectToString {

    private final String delimiter;
    private final List<String> functions;

    public ObjectToString(final String delimiter) {
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
        this.functions = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ObjectToString add(final List<String> func) {
        functions.add(func);
        return this;
    }
///Next lines follows the class implementation code.
}
```

Comment: What is a *conditional constructor*?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public final class ObjectToString {

    private final String delimiter;
    private final List<String> functions = new ArrayList<>();

    public ObjectToString add(final List<String> func) {
        functions.add(func);
        return this;
    }

   // Rest excluded
```

}

No need to create the arraylist in the constructor in your case. If you initialize your field like this, lombok will not create a parameter in the constructor for it.

Relevant part of the lombok documentation:

> @RequiredArgsConstructor generates a constructor with 1 parameter for each field that requires special handling. **All non-initialized final fields get a parameter**, as well as any fields that are marked as @NonNull that aren't initialized where they are declared. 
>   From: https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor